# Is a Disc in $\mathbb R^2$ a symplectic manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, symplectic-geometry

I have no clue about symplectic manifolds but I read about the topic a few days ago and got interested so my question could be trivial.

Anyhow: We consider a Disc in $\mathbb{R}^2$ i.e. $D_R= \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 <  R^2 \}$.

What I have read so far, it is clear that $D_R$ is a 2-dimensional smooth manifold. If we equip the disc with the canonical form $\omega= dx_1\wedge dx_2$ then $(D_R,\omega)$ is a symplectic manifold, right? I would say it is 1-dimensional as it is just the tangent space, but I read that every symplectic manifold must have even dimension.

Can someone help?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is $1$-dimensional as it is just the tangent space"? What do either the first or second "it" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the disk is a symplectic manifold. In fact, any open subset of a symplectic manifold is itself a symplectic manifold, by restricting the symplectic form. Thus, since $(\mathbb{R}^2,dx\wedge dy)$ is a symplectic manifold, the open disk is again a symplectic manifold.

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold and let $U\subseteq M$ be an open subset. Let $\iota^*\omega$ be the pullback of the symplectic form (which is the restriction of $\omega$ to $U$). Then $d\iota^*\omega=\iota^*d\omega=0$. Furthermore, we can canonically identify the tangent space $T_xU$ with $T_xM$, so the form $\omega$ is also non-degenerate on $U$, making the pair $(U,\iota^*\omega)$ into a symplectic manifold.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I totally get it. And whats about the dimension?

Comment: The dimension of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is $n$. In particular, the dimension of the disk is $2$, not $1$. I am not sure where you got this idea. In general, an open subset of a smooth manifold is again a smooth manifold of the same dimension.